# Function keeps resetting itself without being called

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a number guessing game. Unfortunately, the count/guessNo variable keeps resetting itself, indicating that the newGame function is being ended prematurely. This appears  to happen primarily when switching from one guess number to another. Please do not recommend changes to my HTML; this is for an online bootcamp and we are required to use the supplied HTML. Here's my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Hot || Cold</title>

        <!-- Meta Tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/> 

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header> <!--Header -->

            <!-- Top Navigation -->
            <nav> 
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a class="what" href="#">What ?</a></li>
                    <li><a class="new" href="#">+ New Game</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Modal Information Box -->
            <div class="overlay" id="modal">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>What do I do?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>This is a Hot or Cold Number Guessing Game. The game goes like this: </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>1. I pick a <strong>random secret number</strong> between 1 to 100 and keep it hidden.</li>
                            <li>2. You need to <strong>guess</strong> until you can find the hidden secret number.</li>
                            <li>3. You will <strong>get feedback</strong> on how close ("hot") or far ("cold") your guess is.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>So, Are you ready?</p>
                        <a class="close" href="#">Got It!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- logo text -->
            <h1>HOT or COLD</h1>

        </header>

        <section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

            <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

            <form>
                <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
                <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
            </form>

            <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

            <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

            </ul>

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".what").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("a.close").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    newGame();
});

//call newGame when user enters number and presses enter

function newGame() {
    var guessNo = 0;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    $('#guessButton').click(function(){
        guesser(x,guessNo);
});
    $('.new').click(function(){
        newGame();
});
    }

function guesser(x,guessNo) {
    //jQuery
    var guess = parseInt(document.getElementById("userGuess").value, 10);
    var y = Math.abs(x-guess);
    var r = "";
    //switch statement
    if ((guess > 100) || (guess < 1) || (isNaN(guess) == true)) {
        r = "please enter a number between 1 and 100";
    }
    else if (y >= 50) {
        r = "Ice cold";
    }
    else if (y >= 30) {
        r = "cold";
    }
    else if (y >= 20) {
        r = "warm";
    }
    else if (y >= 10) {
        r = "hot";
    }
    else if (y >= 1) {
        r = "very hot";
    }
    else {
        r = "correct!";
    }
    guessNo += 1;
    //jQuery
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = r;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = guessNo;
    console.log("guess = " + guess);
    console.log("x = " + x);
    console.log("y = " + y);
    console.log("r = " + r);
    return guessNo;
    $('#guessButton').click(function(){
        guesser(x,guessNo);
    });
}
```

Comment: the guesser function is supposed to be part of newGame()?

Comment: hmm the structure of your functions and click events seem a bit odd to me (seems like they are all mostly part of newGame). .What is the benefit of putting everything inside newGame()?

Comment: Just edited it so the functions are not nested inside each other. Still running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. So basically, the problem that I ran into was that the submit button in my original code kept resetting the entire page instead of just processing the information in the textboxes.

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Hot || Cold</title>

        <!-- Meta Tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/> 

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header> <!--Header -->

            <!-- Top Navigation -->
            <nav> 
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a class="what" href="#">What ?</a></li>
                    <li><a class="new" href="#">+ New Game</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Modal Information Box -->
            <div class="overlay" id="modal">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>What do I do?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>This is a Hot or Cold Number Guessing Game. The game goes like this: </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>1. I pick a <strong>random secret number</strong> between 1 to 100 and keep it hidden.</li>
                            <li>2. You need to <strong>guess</strong> until you can find the hidden secret number.</li>
                            <li>3. You will <strong>get feedback</strong> on how close ("hot") or far ("cold") your guess is.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>So, Are you ready?</p>
                        <a class="close" href="#">Got It!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- logo text -->
            <h1>HOT or COLD</h1>

        </header>

        <section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

            <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

            <form>
                <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
                <!-- should not be submit -->
                <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
            </form>

            <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

            <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

            </ul>

        </section>
    </body>
</html>

CSS:

clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #394264;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    height: 96%;
    margin: 0.8em auto;
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #1F253D;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul li { 
    display: inline;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Header Styles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    float: right;
}

nav a {

    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3em;
    padding: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;

}

/*style for hidden modal*/
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #e74c3c;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

.content {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e74c3c;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: 15%;
    margin: auto auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.content h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.content > div {
    padding: 15px 40px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.content > div p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: justify;
}

.content > div ul {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.content > div ul li {
    padding: 5px 0;
    display: block; 
    list-style-type: disc;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content > div ul li strong{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content > div a {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #1F253D;
    color: #95a5a6;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Game Section Styles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.game {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #394264;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    box-shadow: rgb(26, 31, 52) 1px 1px,
    rgb(26, 31, 52) 2px 2px,
    rgb(26, 31, 52) 3px 3px,
    rgb(26, 31, 53) 4px 4px,
    rgb(26, 32, 53) 5px 5px,
    rgb(27, 32, 53) 6px 6px,
    rgb(27, 32, 54) 7px 7px,
    rgb(27, 32, 54) 8px 8px,
    rgb(27, 32, 54) 9px 9px,
    rgb(27, 33, 55) 10px 10px,
    rgb(27, 33, 55) 11px 11px,
    rgb(28, 33, 55) 12px 12px,
    rgb(28, 33, 56) 13px 13px,
    rgb(28, 34, 56) 14px 14px,
    rgb(28, 34, 56) 15px 15px,
    rgb(28, 34, 57) 16px 16px,
    rgb(29, 34, 57) 17px 17px,
    rgb(29, 34, 57) 18px 18px,
    rgb(29, 35, 58) 19px 19px,
    rgb(29, 35, 58) 20px 20px,
    rgb(29, 35, 58) 21px 21px,
    rgb(29, 35, 59) 22px 22px,
    rgb(30, 35, 59) 23px 23px,
    rgb(30, 36, 59) 24px 24px,
    rgb(30, 36, 60) 25px 25px,
    rgb(30, 36, 60) 26px 26px,
    rgb(30, 36, 60) 27px 27px,
    rgb(31, 37, 61) 28px 28px;

}

h2 {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: #cc324b;
    padding: 1em 0.4em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}

.game p {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#count {
    color: #f39c12;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.8em 0;
    margin: 0.8em auto 0;
    background: #50597b;
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #1f253d;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

input.button {
    background: #1F253D;
    color: #95a5a6;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
}

input.button:hover {
    background: #e64c65;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #95a5a6;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #95a5a6;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #95a5a6; 
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #95a5a6; 
}

ul.guessBox {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    background: #11a8ab;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}
ul.guessBox li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #1a4e95;
    padding: 0.3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0.2em;
    color: #fff;
}

Javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".what").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    gameState = {};
    $("a.close").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $('#guessButton').click(function(){
        guesser();
        console.log("test");
});
    $('.new').click(function(){
        newGame();
    });

});

function newGame() {
    gameState.guessNumber = 0;
    gameState.number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; 
}

function guesser() {
    //jQuery
    event.preventDefault();
    var x = gameState.number
    var guess = parseInt($('#userGuess').val());
    var y = Math.abs(x-guess);
    var r = "";
    if ((guess > 100) || (guess < 1) || (isNaN(guess) == true)) {
        r = "please enter a number between 1 and 100";
    }
    else if (y >= 50) {
        r = "Ice cold";
    }
    else if (y >= 30) {
        r = "cold";
    }
    else if (y >= 20) {
        r = "warm";
    }
    else if (y >= 10) {
        r = "hot";
    }
    else if (y >= 1) {
        r = "very hot";
    }
    else {
        r = "correct!";
    }
    gameState.guessNumber ++;
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = r;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = gameState.guessNumber;
    console.log("guess = " + guess);
    console.log("x = " + x);
    console.log("y = " + y);
    console.log("r = " + r);
    //return guessNo;
}
```